# Spring boot application not starting tomcat

Tags: maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I have written web service using spring boot.
When I run it it is just doing build and run as JVM

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringTestApplication.class, args);
      }

    }
```

---

```
   .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

    2019-07-10 09:25:01.964  INFO 683 --- [ main] com.example.demo.SpringTestApplication   : Starting SpringTestApplication on     Amits-MacBook-Air.local with PID 683 (/Users/amitpatil/Downloads/demo/target/classes started by amitpatil in /Users/amitpatil/Downloads/demo)
    2019-07-10 09:25:01.967  INFO 683 --- [ main] com.example.demo.SpringTestApplication   : No active profile set, falling back     to default profiles: default
    2019-07-10 09:25:03.298  INFO 683 --- [ main] com.example.demo.SpringTestApplication   : Started SpringTestApplication in     7.067 seconds (JVM running for 7.826)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: please share your pom.xml

Comment: You don't have an appropriate stater on the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying that the `Process finished with exit code 0` means that everything worked **ok**. If an exception occurs in your program or otherwise an exit is generated with non-zero argument.

I recommend use [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) to bootstrap your spring boot application with `embedded tomcat`. Additionally I suggest `Intelliju IDE` to work on your application. This should heads up your application development with ease.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen and is totally fine if you have no process defined that is meant to be running forever. For example if you create a web application you will end up with a `DispatcherServlet` which makes your application stay in running state and waiting for duty.
If that is what you intended to do I would suggest to extend the SpringBootApplication with the proper class. I believe it was `ServletInitalizer` or something.